# Using .annotate() in django migrate

Tags: django, python-3.x, migration

I've encountered a very strange bug. I have a django migration that runs this query:

```
venues = Venue.objects.annotate(num_activities=Count('activities'))\
    .filter(num_activities=1, activities__activity__code="GOLF", timings=None)\
    .all()
```

The query itself works when the database is already up to date, but when initialising the database from scratch (running all migrations from 0001_initial), I get the error:

> *** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'activities' into field.

So that migration fails. But if I run it again, with the database now in a partially migrated state (i.e. going only from 0065 -> 0066), it works just fine.

Any ideas about why it wouldn't work when running from scratch? Is there a bug in the django migration script? Seems to be due to the `.annotate()` function.

Comment: Is the activities field defined prior to using it in the annotate method? Also, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)... don't think it's relevant, but worth checking out.

Comment: Also also, this isn't really and answer but a workaround... you can always [squash migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) if having this exception is a problem.

Comment: Yes, the field is defined prior to using it. Same situation is true for all my related fields. Again, only on a migrate from 0001_initial. If it runs from half-way it works just fine. Really strange...

Comment: Try a fresh migration from 0001_initial, but instead of running `migrate` run [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate)... it'll show you when each `create` statement is being run and whether they're out of order.